# No module named ‘T’ is imported---but I just imported it

Tags: haskell, import

This seems as simple as possible:

```
import Data.Text as T

let x = "test"
T.putStrLn x
```

But I get:

```
<interactive>:1:1: error:
    Not in scope: ‘T.putStrLn’
    No module named ‘T’ is imported.
```

Why is T not imported?  Why is `Data.Text` not imported as T?

Comment: Have you tried importing it in a qualified manner?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`putStrLn` is not provided by [`Data.Text`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/text-1.2.3.1/docs/Data-Text.html), but [`Data.Text.IO`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/text-1.2.3.1/docs/Data-Text-IO.html).
The error message is actually confusing.
I'll check if the problem is reported.

Comment: It is reported (by me) and fixed in newer GHCs.